# mysqli to get info from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Trying to get info from the database into a table. Below is the code I am using but it is not populating the table. The site comes up but no info from the database. Please help, I am very new to this php thing and have no idea what I am doing apart from Google!

```
    <body>
 <?php include("header.php"); ?>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$query = "SELECT * FROM 'teacher'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

echo "<div align=\"center\">";
echo "<table width=\"100%\">";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>First Name</th>";
echo "<th>Middle Name</th>";
echo "<th>Last Name</th>";
echo "</tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['first_name'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['middle_name'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['last_name'];
echo "</td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you are still learning php and mySQL then it is a good idea to start learning PDO instead of mysqli.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'teacher'";
```

should be

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `teacher`";
```

Comment: or even without the backtics

Comment: Why not simply `$query = "SELECT * FROM teacher";`? The backticks are not required here...

Comment: But the backticks are good to adopt, in case you have column names that are the same as functions; like `SELECT max FROM foo` would fail without the use of backticks.

Comment: I know its not required but its a good practice to have backticks always since sometime unknowingly people use reserved keyword in mysql table and this practice of adding backticks eliminate errors on queries those tables, and I follow this rule rigorously.

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT * FROM teacher"
```

Just remove your quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM teacher";
```